# Relation between tensor product of Hilbert spaces and the Kronecker product of their elements

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, kronecker-product, quantum-computation

Consider a task of calculating the basis coefficients of a vector belonging to a tensor product of two Hilbert spaces.

Some definitions first. Take two Hilbert spaces $(A,(\cdot,\cdot)_A)$ and $(B,(\cdot,\cdot)_B)$ as they usually defined in quantum computing textbooks. For $A$, $|a\rangle \in A$ is a generic vector and  $\{|a_i\rangle\}$ (variable-indexed) are basis vectors, so $\forall |a\rangle \exists \alpha_i : |a\rangle = \sum_i\alpha_i|a_i\rangle$. Note that $(|a_i\rangle,|a_j\rangle)_A = \langle a_i|a_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ ($1$ if $i=j$, $0$ otherwise). Same things for $B$.

Now consider a Hilbert space tensor product $(A\otimes B,(\cdot,\cdot)_{AB})$ where the mapping $\otimes : (A \times B)\to(A\otimes B)$ is bilinear and
$$((a_1\otimes b_1),(a_2\otimes b_2))_{AB} \triangleq (a_1,a_2)_A\cdot(b_1,b_2)_B$$

We know that $a_i\otimes b_j$ (spelled as $|a_ib_j\rangle$) is a basis in $A\otimes B$ so for any $a\otimes b $ (aliased as $|ab\rangle$) there exist $\gamma_{ij}$ such that $|ab\rangle = \sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij} |a_i b_j\rangle$. How to calculate these $\gamma$? A simple approach would be to use the inner product as defined above. Here we go: the coefficient near the $|a_pb_q\rangle$ basis vector is:

$$
\gamma_{pq} = \langle a_p b_q|ab\rangle =_1 \langle a_p b_q|\sum_{ij}\alpha_i \beta_j |a_ib_j\rangle =_2 \sum_{ij}\alpha_i\beta_j\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq} = \alpha_p\beta_q
$$
where $=_1$ follows from the bilinearity of $\otimes$, and $=_2$ follows from the definition of $(\cdot,\cdot)_{AB}$.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct to say that the above formula still does not define the Kronecker product of matrix representations of $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ because we didn't specify the order of basis coefficients in the corresponding matrices?
2. Is it the only possible way to derive $\gamma$? Do we have any reasons to assume that $\gamma_{pq} = \alpha_p\beta_q$ without referring to $(\cdot,\cdot)_{AB}$ i.e. from the fact that $A\otimes B$ is a valid tensor product plus maybe some other facts?
3. Why do we use the $(\cdot,\cdot)_{AB}$ as defined above in quantum computing? Is it a direct result of physical experiments or there are pure mathematical reasons to do so?

Comment: Regarding 3, you might find [this Physics SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417955/26959) regarding tensor products in quantum mechanics to be helpful.

Comment: Indeed, Postulate 4, and the following text from the link both touch the problem I'm trying to understand. Wiki article says that the generic tensor product is defined up to an isomorphism. In quantum computing we use a very specific tensor product and the key part of it seems to be the combined inner product defined for it (is it?). In (3) I am wondering if we should treat this way of mixing spaces as an axiom or one can derive it from some other principles?

Comment: There are multiple equivalent ways to define the tensor product, and I think that taking the inner product rule as an axiom is the most sensible approach in this context